# How to convert a four dimensional Tensor to image by PIL?

Tags: python, pytorch

For example, if my tensor is

```
t1 = torch.randn(1,3,256,256) #batch_size/ch/height/width
```

it is easily to convert to one image by `squeeze()`

```
import torchvision.transforms as T
transform = T.ToPILImage()
one_img = transform(t1.squeeze())
one_img.save("test1.jpg")
```

The problem is if batch_size is is more than one, I was wondering if there is for function in pytorch like,

```
t1 = torch.randn(5,3,256,256)
print(t1.shape)
for i in range(t1[0]):
    one_tensor = t1[i]  #(3,256,256)
    one_img = transform(one_tensor)
    one_img.save(i + ".jpg")
```

Comment: I found another method, `from torchvision.transforms import ToPILImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
for i in range(len(t1)):
    one_tensor = t1[i]
    one_img = transform(one_tensor)
    one_img.save(str(i) + ".jpg")
```